# Android Credential Manager almost always return No credentials available for first request

Tags: android, credential-manager

I am sending GetCredentialRequest with preferImmediatelyAvailableCredentials=true on initial screen after checking firebase auth status and some other states. Credential manager usually returns with No credentials. I can only get saved credentials after several attempts. What's best way to call GetCredentialRequest opportunistically?

Comment: Is the credential available locally? If not I think preferImmediatelyAvailableCredentials should be set to false

Comment: @anhtuannd, I think you didn't understand the question. I am specifically writing about local credentials.

Comment: It wasn't mentioned in your original post. It's important to know which kind of credential you try to get, how your code is, ... Otherwise we can only say the best sample about using GetCredentialRequest opportunistically is in Android documentation.